# Twitter ruby gem .search request multiple responses

Tags: ruby, twitter, twitter-gem

In the following code I specify that I want to make 1 request to the twitter api, but when I `puts` the output to terminal I continue to receive many responses until I kill the program. How can I limit it to only the specified amount of requests? I am new to ruby so I may be missing something obviously here.

[Docs to the twitter gem api](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Search)

```
require 'twitter'

...

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|

  config.consumer_key        = credentials[:consumer_key]
  config.consumer_secret     = credentials[:consumer_secret]
  config.access_token        = credentials[:access_token]
  config.access_token_secret = credentials[:access_token_secret]

end

search_results = client.search "China", {:count => 1, :lang => 'en', :result_type => 'recent'}

search_results.each do |value|

    puts value.user.screen_name

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As docs state,

> :count (Integer) — The number of tweets to return per page, up to a
>   maximum of 100.

So, that is kinda reverse for what you're trying to achieve: the more `count` is, the less http requests you gonna make (as each of them would contain more tweets). Note that you can not set `count` to an amount more than 100, so the only way to restrict amount of requests in case there is a huge amount of tweets would be

```
search_results.take(requests_amount)
# => made requests_amount requests, returns requests_amount pages
# each of page should contain up to count tweets, with max of 100
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand how I can stop the multiple requests. For example, I only want one api response with 10 tweets.

Comment: @Nikita set `count` param to 10 and do not iterate through response pages ( = don't use `each`). `search_results.first` should be enough